# Tornado and Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, tornado

does tornado accept unicode in the adress?

```
#coding: utf-8 (there is # dont know how to show it here...)
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class Abdou(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write("hi")

miaw = tornado.web.Application([
(u'/ééé', Abdou),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  miaw.listen(8000)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop
```

in Flask it worked !!!

```
from flask import Flask
miaw = Flask(__name__)

@miaw.route(u'/ééé')
def abdou():
  return "hi!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  miaw.run()
```

NB: the same problem when using escape like /hello world , but in Flask it works!

NB2: thank you "wisty" for the edit :) now it appears more professional as a code :p

Comment: No prob. To get the code highlighting, just indent the code.

Comment: thank you :D now i got several things in just 5 minutes!!! thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `tornado.escape.url_escape(value)` and `tornado.escape.url_unescape(value, encoding='utf-8')`.

Something like this:

```
#coding: utf-8 (there is # dont know how to show it here...)
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class Abdou(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("hi")

miaw = tornado.web.Application([
(tornado.escape.url_escape(u'/ééé'), Abdou),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    miaw.listen(8000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop
```

You probably also want to be able to get urls that the user inputs. I think you do it like:

```
class Page(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,title):
        title = tornado.escape.url_unescape(title, encoding='utf-8')
        self.write(title)


miaw = tornado.web.Application([
(tornado.escape.url_escape(u'/ééé/(*.)'), Page),
])
# you can get /ééé/page_name, where page_name can be unicode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    miaw.listen(8000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop
```

Comment: am sorry, but i'm a beginner, and in Flask (which also am a beginner in) i just run the /something and it make it :)
so how do i change the code here?

Comment: am sorry, but the first one dident work, dont know why!!!! i've even added import tornado.url_escape but nothing changed, always there is the 404 not found :(

Answer (score 0):

it seems that it's a bug:

http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/1f89cbeee05ba6fb/c028d3e4744eec8a?lnk=gst&q=unicode#c028d3e4744eec8a

and the link is dead :( the 404 is following me even here!