# does Tornado uses WSGI to deal with python files?

Tags: python, wsgi, tornado

am sorry for that question,

am beginning in Tornado, and because i come from two other frameworks: Flask and Django, Flask uses Werkzeug which is a WSGI webserver, Django uses WSGI too, but, when making an application programmed with Tornado, how it will deal with HTTP? there is a protocol to deal with python files when it comes to internet? or do i mess something about WSGI?

NB: i know also that Tornado has a WSGI support, for example it can serve Django application, but i mean with a native Tornado application, which protocol it uses?

Comment: NB: there is a good WSGI presentation, i love how it is made :)
http://archimedeanco.com/wsgi-tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tornado shouldn't use WSGI, because WSGI is not async friendly. It has WSGI support, but it won't support async.

Tornado has its own HTTP server (written in C and Python), and can be used standalone or placed behind another async HTTP server (usually Nginx).

Comment: so as i understand, if a framework has its own HTTP server, it will not use WSGI since WSGI is only used to deal with "existing" frameworks?

Comment: Yes. WSGI is a way of connecting frameworks to a web server. Tornado *can* connect to a web server using WSGI, but it's not a good way, as WSGI is a poor fit for Tornado. You usually just proxy stuff through to it.

Comment: thank you :)
now i understand well the concept, but please, can you help me here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100049/tornado-and-unicode